# When is the first call in pollingEvery() method?

Tags: selenium, polling, duration, fluentwait

I'm working on Selenium now and I have to use FluentWait. There's a line in my code which led me straight here.

```
    .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(250))
```

When is the first call? Is it at the moment I run the code or after 250 millis?

I've been looking for the answear but all I got was that Selenium checks if the WebElement is visible every 250 millis (in this case).

```
FluentWait <WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait <> (driver);
WebElement myWorldMessage = fluentWait
.withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
.pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(250))
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='finish']/h4")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It checks immediately and then polls (checks again) every 250ms.

You might check into `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions`. `WebDriverWait` extends `FluentWait` but uses some defaults and is easier to set up. Your code would turn into

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='finish']/h4")));
```

See [the sources](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.java#L33).